# Dynamically getting autowired object container->get

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, doctrine-orm, annotations

Just like normal doctrine entity has an `repositoryClass` annotation I would like to create my own annotation for a different class and dynamically retrieve it autowired from a container.

In the code example below what should the `$this->symfonyContainer` be to retrieve an autowired `repositoryClass`.

```php
<?php
readonly class EntityInfo
{
    public function __construct(
        public string $repositoryClass,
    ) {
    }
}

#[EntityInfo(repositoryClass: AuthDataRepository::class)]
readonly class AuthData
{
}

class Processor
{
    public function getRepositoryObject(string $entityClass)
    {
        $reflection = new ReflectionClass($entityClass);
        $attributes = $reflection->getAttributes(EntityInfo::class);
        if (1 > count($attributes)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Multiple definitions of EntityInfo annotation.');
        }

        $attribute = $attributes[0];
        $info = new $attribute['name'](...$attribute['arguments']);
        assert($info instanceof EntityInfo);

        return $this->symfonyContainer->get($info->repositoryClass);
    }
}
```

~Thanks

Comment: EntityManager ?